# MeetRTC demo not connected to web

Tags: ios, webrtc, jitsi

https://github.com/Teamxrtc/MeetRTC_iOS

I am running MeetRTC demo app to connect into browser room already created in safari. But I have error Socket closed. Stream end encountered. For instance, https://meet.jit.si/apple in browser
bridge - room name in iOS app

How I can fix that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Safari on the Mac and iOS does not support WebRTC. Apple are rumoured to have plans to support it, but have made no announcements as yet